# Какой FrameWork больше подходит для создания Социальной Сети: Codeigniter или Yii?

Tags: php, yii, codeigniter

Главное - скорость разработки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если предполагается что соц сеть будет расти, то выбирай Yii, этот фреймворк динамично развивается и имеет большое сообщество. Codeigniter в этом плане довольно слабовато меняется.

Answer (score 6):

С точки зрения скорости разработки однозначно тот с которым вы работали и лучше знаете.
Если с нуля то во всех обзорах пишут что порог вхождения в CodeIgniter один из самых низких. И вообще вопрос выбора фреймворка неоднократно обсуждался и здесь и на многих форумах.

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter подходит для небольших проектов. Для социальной сети я бы порекомендовал Yii-Framework. Именно на нем я пишу сейчас свою соц-сеть: rooland.ru - изначально всё делал на CI, но потом всё переписал, чтобы не тратить время потом, лучше сразу выбрать Yii.